# Dojo - request.get - .Uncaught TypeError: request.get(...).then(...).catch is not a function

Tags: node.js, dojo

Error on the .catch below in Dojo:

```
<button id="queryStudentId" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button"
        data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitIconTask', 
        onClick:function(){ 
            console.debug('clicked simple');
            var studId = dojo.byId('studentId').value;
            dom.byId('studentFeedback').value += 
                'queryStudentId clicked studentID=' + studId + '\n'; 
            // AJAX Get the data from the server
            var url = '../student/' + dom.byId('studentId').value; 
            dom.byId('studentFeedback').value += url + '\n'; 
            require(['dojo/request'], function(request){
                request.get(url)
                      .then(function(response){
                        dom.byId('studentFeedback').value += response;
                    //})
                    //.catch(function(response){
                    //  dom.byId('studentFeedback').value += response;
                    //});   
                    },
                     function(error){
                        dom.byId('studentFeedback').value += response;
                     }); 
            })
        }">
    Query with Above StudentId
</button>
```

When I tried using the .catch in the sample above, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: request.get(...).then(...).catch is not a function

I don't understand why the .catch won't work, and why substituting the error function does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promises in dojo do not have a .catch() function.

Instead, you should use [.otherwise()](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/promise/Promise.html#otherwise)

```
request.get(url)
  .then(function(response) {
    dom.byId('studentFeedback').value += response;
  })
  .otherwise(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Passing a callback function as a second argument of [.then()](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/promise/Promise.html#then) is also a correct way to capture the errors returned by the promise, as per the documentation.